# MacBook Pro equipped with 16 GB RAM, never uses more than 8 GB

Tags: macbook-pro, mojave, memory

I have an early 2015 MacBook Pro equipped with 16 GB RAM. The computer however appears to be never using more than 8 GB. This is a screenshot of `htop` with the computer under heavy load (Large `postgres` GIST index building):

[image: htop screenshot]

Mac system params look good:

[image]

I'd appreciate if anyone has a clue as to what is going on. I am running macOS Mojave, but the problem has existed ever since I bought the computer.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different :) It could very well be a problem with postgres than the hardware. A quick web search reveals this: https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/111195/postgresql-doesnt-use-all-the-ram-it-could

Comment: Install Chrome and see if it changes.

Comment: What does Activity Monitor show?

Comment: I have a better question... why do you think it should be using more than 8gb of RAM?

Comment: what do you consider as a heavy load?  Try opening several large apps and see what happens.  If you are running one app doing a lot it may not need much memory just cpu cycles.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no problem. Your computer is working as intended.

A computer does not “run faster” by using more memory. Memory is only used (allocated) when programs ask for memory. If they don’t ask for it, it’s not used. This is the preferred behavior as it makes your computer run faster and use less power without sacrificing anything really.

There’s no “8 GB limit” in Mojave, nor in your MacBook Pro hardware.

If you want to simulate  program that is asking for lots of memory, then open the Terminal and run this command:

```
perl -E 'my $x = "abcd1234" x 500000000; sleep(30);'
```

It should allocate lots of memory and hold it for 30 seconds, and then give it back.

You should be able to see it in Activity Monitor allocating ~8 GB of RAM. If you want to allocate more/less, then change the number "500000000" accordingly.

Comment: This. I thought the comment above to try installing chrome was funny.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, makes a lot of sense. The thing that makes me keep scratching my head is why I usually see the memory consumption circa 8Gb and never ever passing that mark.

I'll ask differently. How could I test that, upon request, the system will indeed make use of the 16Gb.

Comment: @c99 I have updated the answer with how to simulate large memory usage.

Comment: @jksoegaard As you said, the computer works fine. Activity monitor does show how perl takes/reserves the memory. Thanks for your help and your replies.